# Force VPN clients to use the on-site DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, vpn

We currently use RAS on a server 2008 for VPN access to our network.

The problem is that the hosts connected to the network through that VPN can't resolve onsite names.

Ex:
$remoteuser on $remotecomputer connects to corp VPN server.
If $remoteuser tries to ping $onsiteserver using its hostname it fails.
Pinging the servers IP works fine.

Clearly the client still uses its local DNS server (home router). 
So when $remotecomputer tries to resolve $onsiteserver the request gets to $remoteuser's home router, which just shrugs and sends the resolution request to the internet.

Is there any way to force the clients to use on-site DNS server for resolution (when they are connected to the VPN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name resolution issues wasn't related to which dns server was used, but rather that the RAS "DHCP" pool did not send DNS suffix info.

So while i couldn't ping "remoteserver" i could ping "remoteserver.contoso.local".
I added the DNS suffix to the RAS DHCP and now it works fine.